# copy from s3 to redshift with a non standard delimiter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy, amazon-redshift

This has given me some serious headache. I have a simple table in redshift

```
create table data.texttest(
    col1 int null,
    col2 int null,
    col3 varchar(256) null,
    col4 int null,
    col5 int null
);
```

and the following say as a gzipped file, where row separator is LF(no CR)

```
col-1þcol-2þcol-3þcol-4þcol5
1268437þ1268437þSome Textþ0þ
1268437þ1268443þSome Textþ0þ
1268437þ1881096þSome Textþ0þ
1268437þ1881109þSome Textþ0þ
1268437þ1881114þSome Textþ0þ
1268437þ1881115þSome Textþ0þ
1268437þ1881129þSome Textþ0þ
1268437þ2807685þSome Textþ0þ
2931841þ2931841þSome Textþ0þ
1268437þ3368478þSome Textþ0þ
1268437þ4339135þSome Textþ0þ
1268437þ4357980þSome Textþ0þ
1268437þ4483058þSome Textþ0þ
```

Loading is simple...

```
copy data.texttest (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) from 's3://<bucket>/<file_name>.log.gz' with credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<>;aws_secret_access_key=<>' delimiter '\376' gzip ignoreheader 1;`
```

but alas... no. I keep getting the following ruddy error on col1

> 1214 | Delimiter not found

When i manually replace þ (small thorn, '\376') with a comma, redshift is happy. Obviously I cant change it so in the actual process. Am I missing some thing here?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delimiter must be ASCII ([COPY documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html))

> Single ASCII character that is used to separate fields in the input
>   file

So some pre-processing will be necessary. The `sed` answer is a good one, this can also be combined with SSH ingestion (instead of copy) so you can amend the character in a stream 'on the way in' rather than re-writing the data first.

A second approach, a bit of a bodge, would be to load into a staging table with a single text column via COPY, and then process that into your target table with a combination of [SPLIT_PART](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/SPLIT_PART.html) and a `create target as select split_part(...` or `insert into... select split_part(...` style query. Split_part doesn't requires its delimiter to be ASCII, at least not according to the documentation.

Comment: ...but they do say

`Non-printing ASCII characters are supported. ASCII characters can also be represented in octal, using the format '\ddd', where 'd' is an octal digit (0-7).`

Comment: ssh integration is an option but again that will mean reading the file line by line and like i mentioned that is not a feasible option due to the size/ number of rows

second approach has potential, but like you said it is a bit over the top and would make pipe line much more complex

Comment: Yes, Non-printing ASCII characters **are** allowed, but your delimiter isn't ASCII, non-printing or otherwise.  I would got with the SPLIT_PART approach, I don't think its too complicated and would mean you can load from S3 without first mangling the files.

Answer (score 0):

we have been experiencing the same issue, we solved it replacing the þ character with the tab character.

If you are using linux to load the data you can use the following command:

sed -i 's/þ/\t/g' /your/file/path/file_name.extension

The option -i allow the command to overwrite the original file. To keep the original file use:

sed -e 's/þ/\t/g' /your/file/path/file_name.extension > newfile_name.extension

Comment: But that would mean in aws terms
`Download the file form s3` -> `Unzip the file` -> `run **sed**` -> gzip it-> `upload the file back to s3`-> `load to redshift`
not a very efficient pipe line now is it? But like you said that seems to be a limitation..damn you aws :D